# Create a usercontrol with a ScrollView

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, scrollviewer

I have a WPF project.

In this project I have a UserControl with a StackPanel containing various elements. It's within a cell in a Grid. When i resize the Windwo and the Cell becomes to small to fit the Stackpanel I want the scrollview to take over.

I tried putting *TheUserControl* in a  but that only seems to work with Set size. I need it to adjust to the dynamic cell size. All "Solutions" I found online have been unnecessary difficult workarounds for such a simple and commen problem. So I'm pretty sure that there is an easy way to achive this behaviour.

**Pseudo-Code**

*The UserControl:*

```
<UserControl x:class=x.TheUserControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Label 01 />
        <Label Content="Label 02 />
        <Label Content="Label 03 />
                     .
                     .
                     .
        <Label Content="Label n />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

*The Window:*

```
<Window x:Class="x.MainWindow>
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Header" />

    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
        <x:TheUserControl />
    </ScrollView>

</Window>
```

I'm pretty sure ScrollView works just fine when i put a StackPAnel directly into the ScrollView, so why is it so complicated with a UserControl inbetween?

I'm properly unaware of some obvious behavior in ScrollView and I would be really glad if someone could show me a better approach or explain why it beahaves this way.

Comment: Do you want to scroll in your UserControl or do you want to scroll in your mainwindow?

Comment: Inside of the UserControl

Comment: I would have thought the common solution to this sort of thing is to use an itemscontrol like a listbox instead of a usercontrol. And of course a listbox comes with a scroller. Why a usercontrol?

Comment: I use a usercontrol because I want to use it multiple Times and not just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the ScrollViewer inside of your usercontrol and use HorizontalScrollBarVisibility & VerticalScrollBarVisibility:

userControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.TheUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             >
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Background="LightGray">
                <Label Content="Label 01" />
                <Label Content="Label 02" />
                <Label Content="Label 03" />
                <Label Content="Label n" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <Grid Background="Aqua">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Header" Grid.Row="0" />
        <local:TheUserControl Grid.Row="1" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result, if you resize the window:

[image: Usercontrol with Scrollviewer inside]

Comment: Sadly no changes are visible. Also I think *auto* and *vertical* are the default values there, so setting them should be redundant. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Griizz: Please have a look at my answer. Is this the expected result?

Comment: Yes thats the expected outcome. Sadly it dosent work in my project and i am not allowed to post any Code of this project.
I have just one question. Why the grid in the usercontrol?